# PostgreSQL installer disappears into the background

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am trying the PostgreSQL Windows 10 installer for the first time. But after clicking the installer I see a window pop and disappearing almost directly. And thats it... In the task manager I can see the install process. But it is not doing anything.

Steps performed:

1. Running the installer as Admin
2. Checking the temp folder and event viewer for errors (none found)

Background:

Installer: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads (postgresql-13.1-1-windows-x64)

**This the log of the installation I could find the temp directory:**

```
Log started 11/25/2020 at 16:38:17
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Setting variable whoami from C:\WINDOWS\System32\whoami 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 MyUserName

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\WINDOWS\System32\icacls "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_0d4826705d" /inheritance:r
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 processed file: C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_0d4826705d
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\WINDOWS\System32\icacls "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_0d4826705d" /T /Q /grant "MyUserName:(OI)(CI)F"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

Script stderr:
 

Executing C:\WINDOWS\System32\cscript //NoLogo "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_0d4826705d\prerun_checks.vbs"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 The scripting host appears to be functional.

Script stderr:
 

Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value
[16:38:22] Using branding: PostgreSQL 13
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 SB_Version. Setting variable sb_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 pgAdmin_Version. Setting variable pgadmin_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 CLT_Version. Setting variable clt_version to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Data Directory. Setting variable server_data_dir to empty value
Executing C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_0d4826705d/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 "test ok"

Script stderr:
 

Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Data Directory. Setting variable iDataDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Base Directory. Setting variable iBaseDirectory to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Service ID. Setting variable iServiceName to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Service Account. Setting variable iServiceAccount to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Super User. Setting variable iSuperuser to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Branding. Setting variable iBranding to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Version. Setting variable brandingVer to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 Shortcuts. Setting variable iShortcut to empty value
Could not find registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-13 DisableStackBuilder. Setting variable iDisableStackBuilder to empty value
[16:38:23] Existing base directory: 
[16:38:23] Existing data directory: 
[16:38:23] Using branding: PostgreSQL 13
[16:38:23] Using Super User: postgres and Service Account: NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService
[16:38:23] Using Service Name: postgresql-x64-13
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did try Powershell and Cmd, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

in my computer, set computer name in Chinese will cause this problem C:\WINDOWS\System32\icacls "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_XXXXXXXXXX" /T /Q /grant "XXX"
if I use english name ,it will not fail.